# Check for Independence

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given

$$f_{(U_1,U_2)}(u_1,u_2)=\begin{cases} 1/2& -u_1<u_2<u_1 \text{ and } u_1 - 2 < u_2 < 2 - u_1 \text{ and } 0 < u_1 <2\\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I found that $$f_{(U_1)}(u_1) = \begin{cases} u_1 & 0<u_1<1\\2-u_1 &1<u_1<2 \\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

And $$f_{(U_2)}(u_2) = \begin{cases} 1+u_2 & -1<u_2<0\\1-u_2 &0<u_2<1 \\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

The support I found is a square within a larger square with side 1 centered at the origin and minus four $45$-$45$-$90$ angle with length $1$-$1$-$\sqrt{2}$ at each corner

Since the support for the joint density is a square, I am wondering if $U_1$ and $U_2$ are independent.  How do I check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They shouldn't be independent: we know that $\lvert U_2\rvert<U_1$ with probability $1$. So, *knowledge of the value of $U_1$ gives us information about the possible values of $U_2$*.

With this in mind, it isn't hard to come up with events which disprove this.  For instance:
$P(U_2>\frac{1}{2})>0$, $P(U_1<\frac{1}{2})>0$, but $P(U_2>\frac{1}{2}\text{ and }U_1<\frac{1}{2})=0$. If the events were independent, then of course this last probability would have been positive.

Necessarily, in order for two variables $X$ and $Y$ to be independent, their joint distribution must be supported on a square *with sides parallel to the coordinate axes*.  Otherwise, knowledge of one variable changes the distribution of the other.

(Note, though, that even this isn't a sufficient condition.)

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf No, sorry.

Comment: a minor point: does it matter for the support for joint density and marginal densities if I interchange < with $\le$ or > with $\ge$?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf If you are dealing with functions which have densities, then no; the difference is a set which doesn't contain any area (for the joint density) or which does not contain an interval (for the marginals), so that the difference in probability will be $0$.